# Changing Connection Strings in Web.config to access local database instead of online database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, database-connection

(sorry if this is a stupid question)
I've recently discontinued a site that I created, as well as the online database.

Recently, I've been interested in working on it locally, so I can learn more about web/databases and the like.
The only thing is - I'm not sure how to change the connection string in the `web.config` from the online connection to the local connection. I've already copied the database to a local server in SQL Management Server Studio.

- What's the syntax for using a local database as a connection string?

Here is the old online database connection string:
There's two connections both to the same database (from what I gather, one is due to the user login, the other is for model creation from database)

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=tcp:pokemondaycare.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=PDC-TESTING;Integrated Security=False;User Id=ServerAdmin@pokemondaycare;Password=AzBanks_1;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
<add name="pokemonDayCareDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PDCDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.PDCDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.PDCDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=pokemondaycare.database.windows.net;initial catalog=PDC-TESTING;persist security info=True;user id=ServerAdmin;password=AzBanks_1;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Here is the local database properties
[image: local db properties]

Thanks for any help

Comment: you can use localhost as the servername usually - and for MS-SQL you can use (local) - or just put in the machine name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Data Source` to dot `.` or localhost:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=PDC-TESTING;
            Integrated Security=False;..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be (a sample). Check [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string) for more information

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" 
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
/>
```